# Appending subscriptions with another list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, subscriber

I have a subscription data extension that manages a number of categories of subscriptions, for a given subscriber.

Something happened where their subscription status (boolean) for certain categories was reset to subscribed.

I have a list of subscribers from a previous deployment that I need to append their status in the subscription data extension.

Is there a way to do this with SSJS that would be easier than writing a SQL query using the CASE function on a join from the list that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down the route of using a CASE function within a SQL Query to append the field within a row from a source data extension.